# trying to redirect a link in joomla or .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, dns

we moved our joomla site and rebuilt. in the process a link got moved that we need to be as it was before.
before:
www.mysite.org/kindergym

now it lives here:
www.mysite.org/education/kindergym

it would seem that it would be easy to go into com_redirect and do this. however, it only works for the following
mysite.org/kindergym without the www
with the www attached writing the old url returns a 404 error page, not a redirect.

i tried to make a separate redirect with the www too and it wouldnt let me. i tried a separate module with no success and have played around with the .htaccess file (although i am not very knowledgeable about htaccess).

could someone explain the reason why this would be an issue? the difference between the two. i tried calling my host and they were less than helpful and actually told me what i wanted to do couldnt be done LOL.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I take it the solution you have would work if you redirect the entire mysite.org to www.mysite.org?

If so, create a .htaccess file in the website root. Put the following inside it:

```
########## Begin - Redirecting non-www request to www
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.org [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.org/$1 [L,R=301]
#
########## End - Redirecting non-www request to www
```

You also need to make sure mod_rewrite is enabled on the apache-server, but I think most providers support that.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you post your full .htaccess here. However I think all you need is this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!education/).*)$ education/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers are good! but better implement 301 redirect in *httpd.conf* since it's **compiled** once on server restart. The same code in *.htccess* is **interpreted** for each and every HTTP request!